# Ошибка ORA-12505 при подключении к базе данных

Tags: база-данных, oracle, docker, apple, connection

Помогите решать проблемку. Мне нужно было поставить базу данных Oracle через Docker. И всё было бы ничего, если бы не эта ошибка. Прикрепил фото файлика с которым запускал этот контейнер с базой данных и скриншот команды которую выполнял. Уже не знаю что делать. Работаю на MacBook Air с чипом М1 на архитектуре ARM.[image: Ошибка эта есть что бы я не делал. Уже не знаю что с этим решить. Просидел пол ночи.]
[image: Это файлик конфигурации с которым создавал и запускал базу данных]
[image: А на этом скриншоте снизу команда с помощью которой всё создавалось. В строке которая выше, я проверял наличие активного контейнера (базы данных).]

Comment: А ваш MacBook Air с чипом М1 на архитектуре ARM (кстати, цвет корпуса забыли указать) знает о том, по какому IP адресу доступен хост my.domain.com? Попробуйте  ping хоста.

Comment: А как поднимается контейнер? Приложите строку запуска...